How to Trigger Focus Event in PrimeNG p-autoComplete Component using a directive?
I’m working on an Angular application using the PrimeNG p-autoComplete component. I want to trigger an alert when the element gains focus to indicate that focus is on the element, but it’s not working. I'm using a directive to achieve this, and I’d like to know if anyone has a solution. Here's part of my code:
<p-autoComplete #autocomplete orlyDisableShortcuts class="autocomplete-custom" field="label"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedSearchItem"
    [suggestions]="suggestionsList" [minLength]="3" [delay]="500" [showClear]="true" [group]="true"
    (completeMethod)="searchAutocomplete($event)" (onSelect)="redirectToPage($event)"
    (onHide)="onAutoCompleteClose()" (onClear)="clearAutocomplete();autocomplete.hide()"
    (onFocus)="onAutocompleteFocus();" (onBlur)="onAutocompleteBlur();">
</p-autoComplete>

Directive Code:
@Directive({
  selector: '[orlyDisableShortcuts]'
})
    export class DisableShortcutsDirective implements OnDestroy {
    
      constructor(private shortcutService: ShortcutService) { }
    
      @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target'])
      onFocus(): void {    
        console.log('Focus detected: Disabling shortcuts');
        this.shortcutService.disableShortcuts();
      }
    
      @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target'])
      onBlur(): void {
        console.log('Blur detected: Enabling shortcuts');
        this.shortcutService.enableShortcuts();
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.shortcutService.enableShortcuts();
      }
    }

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Do you have a @Directive decorator on top of your directive? Something like:
@Directive({ selector: '[orlyDisableShortcuts]' })


Hi ilya.chepurnoy yes, I have the Decorator in my directive.

I'm starting to think it doesn't work with the primeNG Autocomplete element, because if I do it with a simple input, it does work

@EdgarConrado who said that you need a directive for your goal, at all?  Can't you just do:
(onFocus)="onAutocompleteFocus(); this.shortcutService.disableShortcuts();" (onBlur)="onAutocompleteBlur(); this.shortcutService.enableShortcuts();"
Yes, I realize that a directive is more concise though.... And also if you do need a directive, try to play with ViewContainerRef, EmbeddedViewRef and thingls like that, to dig deeper into why all this does not work.

Try also https://primeng.org/checkbox, it has onFocus event emitter. I wonder if it will work.

is the directive's conistructor even fired? if it is, maybe then: You can try to put the directive on a wraper div around your autocomplete. Pass its template reference to the directive via @Input.  In the constructor, set up event listeners on it, on focus event, specifying third parameter { capture: true } for addEventListener, which enables event capturing (focus does not bubble). That way, before focus hits the autocomplete, you could be able to trigger your stuff.

Maybe also try deleting ['$event.target'] from the snippet, since you do not use the target anyway, just doing side effects

I use the directive because it can be used in multiple components, but your advice to use onFocus worked for me, thanks

I changed the @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target']) to @HostListener('onFocus', ['$event.target']) and worked
@Directive({
  selector: '[orlyDisableShortcuts]'
})
    export class DisableShortcutsDirective implements OnDestroy {
    
      constructor(private shortcutService: ShortcutService) { }
    
      @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target'])
      onFocus(): void {    
        console.log('Focus detected: Disabling shortcuts');
        this.shortcutService.disableShortcuts();
      }
    
      @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target'])
      onBlur(): void {
        console.log('Blur detected: Enabling shortcuts');
        this.shortcutService.enableShortcuts();
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.shortcutService.enableShortcuts();
      }
    }

